# Locating a graphic function (Python)

Tags: python, graphics

First off, thanks to the site and everybody on it.  I am taking my first python class and have come across this site many times when trouble-shooting coding problems.  Thanks to everybody who have already helped me out a little thus far.  But, I do have a problem I can't figure out:

I have to draw the "5" side of a die in a python graphics window.  The catch is that I can't just draw them.  My "Dot" function has to be called 5 times to complete the graphic.  I had trouble with the dot being placed on the rectangle, but the prof helped me out there.  I just can't seem to locate the same dot in different locations.  Here is my code so far:

```
from graphics import*

def Dot(win):

    # Draw a dot

    center=Point(150,150)
    circ=Circle(center,25)
    circ.setFill('Black')
    circ.draw(win)


def Dice():

    #Build the dice (fill white, background green)
    win=GraphWin('Shapes',500,500)
    win.setBackground('Green')
    rect=Rectangle(Point(100,100),Point(400,400))
    rect.setFill('White')
    rect.draw(win)

    #Call dot 5 times with different locations:

    Dot(win)

    Dot(win)

    Dot(win)

    Dot(win)

    Dot(win)


def main():

    Dice()

main()
```

I have to call the "Dot" function 5 times.  However, I have tried to ".move(pt,pt), .locate, etc.  I can't figure out how to take the "Dot" function and move it to a different location on the graphics window.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that the dot is always drawn at the same point (coordinate), i.e. 5 calls gives 5 circles at the same place?

Comment: The function `Dot` itself always draws on the same place: `center=Point(150,150)`. You'd better find a way to *pass* some other *arguments* to that function (hint, hint).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this one.  I wasn't aware you could command after the window arguement.  So, the Dot(win, 350,150)  etc. with the different coordinates worked well.  Thanks for the responses and help!